# US or British English in Stack Overflow Documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation, english

I was making a spelling correction on some documentation and was about to fix a misspelling of `initialize`.  At the same time, this made me wonder if there is a policy of using US or UK English in the documentation?  If it's UK English, should I be changing this to `initialise` at the same time?

From my experience, technical documentation is *normally* written in US English.

Comment: Given the bulk of questions today, clearly it should be Canadian.  "eh" is a valid sentence.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Same rule as Stack Overflow itself: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

If the spelling variant is the only thing you're tempted to change about an example, there's very likely a better use of your time somewhere else. If you're fixing a typo elsewhere in the word... just keep whatever dialect was originally used.

Comment: Good point, but this does affect search-ability of topics.  Unless documentation search is already fuzzy enough to pick up variations between English automatically.

Comment: @LeopardSkinPillBoxHat Right now the state of search is a bit dire altogether. Still, the core problem here doesn't seem any worse than searching for "initialize" vs "initialise" on SO. Whatever spelling method is used in the framework or language being documented will win out.

Comment: This is very similar to the rule on Wikipedia. If an article is already in one dialect, don't change it.